# Proving $P(A\cap \overline{B})=P(A)-P(A\cap B)$

Tags: probability

how does one formula prove that $P(A\cap \overline{B})=P(A)-P(A\cap B)$. I can show with Venn diagrams that $(A\cap \overline{B})=A\backslash(A\cap B)$ but how does one formally prove it? And is it sufficient to prove this identity to get the identity for the probabilities?

Comment: What do you mean by a "formal proof"?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400575/does-pa-cap-b-pa-cap-bc-pa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $(A\cap B) \cap (A\cap \overline B)=\emptyset$

details:

then
$$
P(A) = P((A\cap B) \cup (A\cap \overline B))
=
P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap \overline B)
$$

Comment: That middle $\cap$ should be a $\cup$.

Comment: No. {}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}

Comment: OK, I see what you are trying to get at, but the OP still needs to figure out what the event $(A\cap B) \cup (A\cap B^c)$ is. Else the first equality of your second (centered and displayed) equation cannot be written down.